# US Banks offering Security Tokens in 2012

Tags: banking, online-banking, security

I'm wondering what banks in the US offer security tokens (keyfobs or an Android app serving the same function). I'm having difficulty digging up any details about this, since every bank happily claims to have two-factor authentication because, see, you gotta choose a picture and tell us your mom's maiden name!

[This exact question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/what-u-s-banks-offer-two-factor-authentication-such-as-password-token-for-o) was asked almost two years ago, but I'm really hoping the situation has improved since then. It seems crazy to me that my email, my web hosting, and even my World of Warcraft accounts are all more secure than my bank accounts.

Comment: I know E*Trade had it for ages, other banks offer it as well. Usually for a fee. Security-wise US banks are way behind the rest of the world though, you're right.

Comment: If your password is still your mom's maiden name, that's your own fault. Contact the bank and change it to something that can't be looked up or guessed. (Took me too long to do that too, admittedly.)

Answer (score 2):

Bank of America "safe-pass" generates a code that is sent to your phone as a text message.

Its an optional feature, this happens during log in, if you enter that code correctly, then you are taken to your more traditional login, which also features the weak (but widely heralded) two-factor authentication which shows a picture you chose and a password field.

Some other banks do other things, but yes, your craigslist phone verification is generally more secure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for another one right now. Here's what I've found:

- Los Alamos National Bank (www.lanb.com) has tokens ($5?), but I think they only open accounts for New Mexico residents. I've had one for several years.
- USAA Savings Bank (usaa.com) has tokens ($5 or free, I don't remember). I'm pretty sure you do NOT need to be a USAA member to open an account. I've had one for a couple of years.
- Several banks (Frost Bank, American National Bank of Texas, Amegy Bank, and probably many, many more) offer them as part of their Treasury Management accounts, meant for big businesses and charged for accordingly.
- Happy State Bank (in, where else, Happy, Texas) has a web page saying they have them but their services charges were more than I wanted to pay.
- ClearSky Bank (an Internet bank started by Chesapeake Bank) claims on their web page to have them but I haven't verified that yet.

Still looking...

Answer (score -1):

Charles Schwab and HSBC offer security tokens.